# How to change the text size of the key on the custom keyboard?

Tags: android

I have a created my custom keyboard and I have obvious many keys on it and every key's has its label, so want I want is to increase the size of the label written on that keys,so far I have found

```
android:labelTextSize
```

[FROM HERE](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/inputmethodservice/KeyboardView.html#attr_android:labelTextSize) so where should I implement this or is there any other way?

this is my keyboard image 
[image]

and I have to make like this one
[image]

As you can see that Q,W, and E alphabets text size is increased

```
<Keyboard xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:horizontalGap="0px"
android:keyHeight="@dimen/key_height"
android:keyWidth="10%p"
android:verticalGap="0px" >

<Row>
    <Key
        android:codes="113"
        android:keyEdgeFlags="left"
        android:keyLabel="q" />
```

Where should I implement these code?

PLEASE HELP ME OUT

Comment: To me `android:keyTextSize` seems more appropriate, at least that's how I understand the description.

Comment: so where should I implement this code?

Comment: use the `android:keyTextSize` property in your layout (probably the xml file) for those letters.

Answer (score 0):

If your Using Paint Class in `KeyboardView` java File

```
Paint paint = new Paint();
```

for setting the TextSize

`paint.setTextSize(32);` it accepts a pixel value,

Try this Let me know :)

Comment: I have not created my custom KeyboardView class

Answer (score -1):

Modify your code like this:

```
<Keyboard xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:horizontalGap="0px"
android:keyHeight="@dimen/key_height"
android:keyWidth="10%p"
android:verticalGap="0px" >

<Row>
    <Key
        android:codes="113"
        android:keyEdgeFlags="left"
        android:keyTextSize="14px"  //add this line
        android:keyLabel="q" />
```

You can play with the value of `android:keyTextSize` to achieve your desired result.